# "sendmail_path" setup using ".user.ini" files is failed (php-fpm)

Tags: php, ini, fpm

I use PHP 7.3:

```
PHP Version 7.3.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Server API  FPM/FastCGI
```

and I need to have different sendmail configurations for different virtual hosts (applications).

I try to use `.user.ini` file to configure PHP parameters:

```
sendmail_from="user@domain.com"
sendmail_path="/usr/bin/agent -c profile1"
```

First parameter is overridden, but second one isn't:
[image]

How can I configure different `sendmail_path` parameters for different virtualhosts/apps if I use PHP-FPM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sendmail_path` is a PHP_INI_SYSTEM class setting, and a `php_admin_value[]` in the FPM pool configuration.
Whereas `sendmail_from` is a standard PHP_INI_ALL option.

Thus you can't override the sendmail binary setting on a .user.ini / directory basis, nor per [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/ini_set).